# How to show reminder by month for Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to show reminder by month?
I have created this partial code and I am stucked how to manipulate to check and get reminder by month.

```
reminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>();

if (reminders.Count<Reminder>() > 0)
{

}
else
{

}
```

If there is reminder I want to check the month and get the month i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
var month = 5; // your month
var remindersOfMonth = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<ScheduledAction>()
                        .Where(a=> a.BeginTime.Month == month);
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh220821%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) when you use GetActions() it will return you a list of 
ScheduledAction. Now according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledaction%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) ScheduledAction has a property called BeginTime which is of type DateTime so it has Month property which is your interest.

variable "a" in the statement is in fact each of ScheduledAction in the collection which are begin evaluated again the month.

Comment: just checking. Should use integer month ( int intMth = 5) ? and what is (a) in the where statement?

Comment: just checking. Should use integer month ( int intMth = 5) ? and what is (a) in the where statement?

Comment: Another issue: Scheduler always accept time US time format. mm/dd/yy. is this the case?  If so, british time format must conver to US time format b4 add the reminder? How to convert the time in your where -statement into British time format?  Thank

Comment: that doesn't matter because you are working with System.DateTime not parsing the string

Comment: Your solution work. I will work on  dateTime. my concern is If the phone is in British Time format ie : 7/13/2011 , I have to change it to 7/13/2011,  DateTime beginTime = "7/13/2011";